# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (python)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and I'm getting the following error message

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

This is my code:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url)

xList = []
labels = []
for line in data:
    row = line.strip().split(",")
```

anyone can help me.   thanks

Comment: Can you wrap your code with stackoverflow's tool? Just add 4 spaces at the start of the line with codes.

Comment: Can you show us `target_url`

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str

Comment: Thanks for all, 

i change my code from:
     row = line.strip().split(",")
to
      row = str(line.strip()).split(",")

and work well.
thanks a lot