# Porting Python 2.x script to Python 3.x at Windows

Tags: python, windows

I start programming with python on a Windows host. While simple examples work for unix like system I have to handle some Windows specifics like the line ending.

The following python script fails with an

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

for the last line of the function `run` in this example:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def run(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
    if stderrdata:
        sys.stderr.write('\n')
        sys.stderr.write(stderrdata)
    return [real_line for real_line in stdoutdata.split('\n') if real_line]

def main():
    run("dir c:\\");
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I guess that this is related to the fact that the stdoutdata contain line endings with `\r\n`. But replacing the split parameter with `'\r\n'` doesn't help.

How can I modify the script to run on a Windows host without changing the tools to start the external program?

Comment: It's not about porting to Windows, it's about porting between Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str

Comment: This is essentially a dupe, even if your error is coming from `.split()` method. Essentially, if you want to split `bytes` type, separator also have to be `bytes`. Use `b"\n"` instead of `"\n"` in write and split calls.

Comment: Have you tried casting it?

Comment: @Afflicted Hmm, will grab a book for that.