# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str': Error Getting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I trying to write output file but getting below error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Can any one please suggest me ?

```
import csv

fin = open('another_summary_table.csv')
words = ["PCB","Switch","Socket","Red-Green LED","Solar Panel","Battery", "Load wire"]
found = {}

wr = csv.writer(open("boop-1.csv", "wb"))
fieldnames = ['PartsReplaced']
writer = csv.DictWriter(fin, fieldnames=fieldnames)
for line in fin:
    split_line=line.split(',')
    str1=split_line[2] # Whatever columns
    PartsReplaced=split_line[2] # Whatever columns

    for w in words:
        if w in str1:
            found[w]=found.get(w,0)+1

            break
wr.writerows(found)
```

Comment: It can't be both python 2 and python 3. Which is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Comment: Python 3, is fine

Comment: Why is this question tagged pandas? You aren't using Pandas in this code, you haven't even imported it.

Comment: change wr = csv.writer(open("boop-1.csv", "wb")) to wr = csv.writer(open("boop-1.csv", "w"))

Comment: @PM 2Ring, If any solution for to solve same problem in pandas

Comment: Since you're using Python 3 you should open both .csv files in text mode. When using the `csv` module in Python 2 you _must_ open the .csv files in binary mode.

Comment: @Shiping, Now not getting error but also not getting data in output file?

Comment: did you try print(found) to see if found actually is not empty? i guess it's empty.

Comment: I have printed found and getting output

Comment: the output file is zero size?

Comment: No I'm getting `{'PCB': 21, 'Battery': 15, 'Solar Panel': 11, 'Switch': 7, 'Red-Green LED': 2, 'Socket': 2}`

Comment: Yes, you are trying to pass a `dict` to the `writerow()` method. Either pass a sequence or use the [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I used `DictWriter` but not getting output. I have edit my code. please check once

Comment: Firstly, make sure you `close()` the file once it's written to. Secondly, none of the keys in  `found` match the field name specified in `fieldnames`.