# split(os.linesep) error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I have this simple code:

```
import subprocess, os
cmd = ['java', '-cp', '/weka.jar', 'weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes', '-t' ,         
       '/MyData.arff']
print (' '.join(cmd))
data = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
data = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in data.split(os.linesep)][0:-1]
print (data)
```

I get this error, when I run it:

```
    data = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in data.split(os.linesep)][0:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t ? See also the related section here : -------------------------------->

Comment: @RC.: reading, not writing, and using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Note the "?"

Answer (score 2):

By default, `subprocess` gives you *bytes* as stdout output. You can't use `'...'` strings with stripping or splitting, you need to use `bytes` objects.

Either tell `subprocess` to decode the data as text for you (using `universal_newlines=True` or by setting an `encoding` argument), or use `bytes.splitlines()` to split your text, and use `.split(b'\t')` to split each line.

Comment: I changed the code to this code :                                                                        data = [line.strip().split(b'\t') for line in bytes.splitlines(data)][0:-1]                                                                           but the data is printed all in one line.

Comment: @RZAKHK: you don't want to remove the last line (when using `str.split()` you'd get an empty string at the end, but `bytes.splitlines()` is smarter). You now have a *list of lists*, just process those. You could use `for row in data: print(*row)` if you want to print the stuff on separate lines.

Comment: Yes, It works now. Thank you.