# Flask Unit Testing and not understanding my fix for "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, tdd

I am currently building a small web application to improve my skills, as part of this, I am trying to go with best practices across the board, testing, CI, well architected, clean code, all of that. Over the last few sessions of working on it, I have been struggling with a test on my root route where instead of returning a string via the route function, I am rendering a template, I have gotten it to work, but I don't understanding why it works, and this bothers me.

Primarily, it's the use of the b, before my assertion string, I assume it is to do with the fact that what I am rendering is not a string, but a html representation, akin to the difference between return and print, but I am hazy and would appreciate for someone to school me.

The line I am asking about is line 4 of the test_homepage_response function. And how it operates. Especially in regards to this error I was getting:

### The error being returned:

```
ERROR: test_home_welcome_return (tests.home_page_tests.HomePageTestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xibalba/code/reel/tests/home_page_tests.py", line 31, in test_home_welcome_return
    self.assertIn(u"Welcome to Reel!", response.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1077, in assertIn
    if member not in container:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

### My tests for the home route:

---

```
# Test Suite
import unittest
from reel import app
from reel.views import home_welcome


class HomePageTesttClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setupClass(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.app.testing = True

    def test_homepage_response(self):
        result = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(b"Welcome to Reel!", result.data)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### My views file:

---

```
from reel import app
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/')
def home_welcome():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route('/signup')
def signup_welcome():
    return 'Welcome to the signup page!'

@app.route('/login')
def login_welcome():
    return 'Welcome to the login page!'

@app.route('/become_a_guide')
def guide_welcome():
    return 'Welcome to the guide page!'

@app.route('/help')
def help_welcome():
    return 'Welcome to the help page!'
```

Some of the resources I used figuring this out, which pointed me towards the use of the b:

https://github.com/mjhea0/flaskr-tdd#first-test

[What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Appreciate this is a long one, I tried to provide as much context because I honestly feel pretty stupid with this question, but I didn't want to just continue on without knowing why the solution I'm using is working.

Thank you as always.

Comment: What does your `result.data` actually look like? FYI never feel stupid when it comes to figuring out bytes and encoding/decoding. It *bites* more people than you think. (I couldn't resist).. :P

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment and kind assurances! 
result.data = b'Welcome to Reel!'

Comment: So, I copy pasted your code, and created a homepage.html file on my end that only included "Welcome to Reel!". I'm using Python 3.5. I can't reproduce. =/.

Comment: Wait, as in you can't reproduce the error? I'm not getting an error with this setup, I was probably wishy washy in my explanation, this one (the quoted code works) but when I remove the b from the string in the assertion, THEN it fails. I just wanted more understanding of why I have to use the b, because I've seen other peoples tests not include the b and I assum they work?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are asking. Apologies. I just wrote up an answer for you to help clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very short simple answer, is that string belongs to the `str` *type*, while "b" in front of a *string* will now make it a *bytes* object, belonging to `type` *bytes*. Therefore, the expectation is that *yes* they should in fact *not* equal to each other because of the comparison of *different* types will be expected to fail.

Furthermore, the assertion you are using `assertIn`, is using the `in` keyword to test. In order to properly test with `in`, you *need* to compare bytes to bytes in this case.

Observe this simple example, that takes you through replicating what you are experiencing:

```
>>> s = "this is a string"
>>> t = "this is another string"
>>> type(s) == type(t)
True
>>> sb = b"this is a string"
>>> type(sb) == type(s)
False
>>> s in sb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So, as you can see, the "b" actually serves a functional purpose here that gives you a different type of "object".

You *could* also *decode* to a string:

```
>>> res = sb.decode()
>>> type(res)
<class 'str'>
```

Suggest being explicit about your decoding, however:

```
>>> res = sb.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(res)
<class 'str'>
```

Finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t) is an excellent more detailed explanation about the *containment* test with `bytes`. Hope this helps.