# PYTHON3 Error with encoding: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to convert a Python 2 script to a Python3.

If i use this part originally written in Python2:

```
def login_data(username, password, csrf_token):
    def encrypt(text):
        m = hashlib.sha256()
        m.update(text)
        return base64.b64encode(m.hexdigest())

    password_hash = encrypt(username + encrypt(password) + csrf_token)
    return '<?xml version:"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><Username>admin</Username><Password>'+password_hash+'</Password><password_type>4</password_type></request>'
```

I receive as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 92, in <module>
    s = login(WEB, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
  File "untitled.py", line 44, in login
    data = login_data(username, password, csrf_tokens[1])
  File "untitled.py", line 66, in login_data
    password_hash = encrypt(username + encrypt(password) + csrf_token)
  File "untitled.py", line 63, in encrypt
    m.update(text)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

If i try to add the encoding:

```
def login_data(username, password, csrf_token):
    def encrypt(text):
        m = hashlib.sha256()
        m.update(text.encode())
        return base64.b64encode(m.hexdigest())

    password_hash = encrypt(username + encrypt(password) + csrf_token)
    return '<?xml version:"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><Username>admin</Username><Password>'+password_hash+'</Password><password_type>4</password_type></request>'
```

I receive as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 92, in <module>
    s = login(WEB, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
  File "untitled.py", line 44, in login
    data = login_data(username, password, csrf_tokens[1])
  File "untitled.py", line 66, in login_data
    password_hash = encrypt(username + encrypt(password) + csrf_token)
  File "untitled.py", line 64, in encrypt
    return base64.b64encode(m.hexdigest())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 59, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t

Comment: Not helpful actually @AviLevin