# Numpy throws error while using genfromtxt function in python 3

Tags: python, numpy

My sample code will be like this

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

data = "1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6"
np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=",")
```

while run this code throws error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I think you want np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(data), delimiter=",") the error suggests it doesn't like the string as is

Comment: shouldn't it be read as BytesIO(data.encode())?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the string before reading it:

```
data = "1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6"
np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(data.encode()), delimiter=",")

array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```