# Is there a more efficient way to convert a multiple line of string to a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am converting a multiple line of string to an numpy array, like this:

```
names = """
1 2 1
1 1 0
0 1 1
"""
names_list = names.splitlines()
tem = []
for i in [row for row in names_list if row]:
    tem.append([col for col in list(i) if col != ' '])

np.array(tem, dtype=np.int)
```

This piece of code works though, I would like to know if is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: if all entries are separated by a space, you can call `i.split(" ")` on the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer was flagged as being low quality for not explaining itself.  But none of the other three do that, and they are just replicas of each other.

```
In [227]: names = """ 
     ...: 1 2 1 
     ...: 1 1 0 
     ...: 0 1 1 
     ...: """    

In [238]: np.genfromtxt(StringIO(names), dtype=int)                                  
Out[238]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
In [239]: timeit np.genfromtxt(StringIO(names), dtype=int)                           
135 µs ± 286 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Actually we don't need the `StringIO` layer; just split the string into lines (sometimes we need a `format=None` parameter):

```
In [242]: np.genfromtxt(names.splitlines(), dtype=int)                               
Out[242]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

The original function is 10x faster than the accepted one(s):

```
def orig(names):
    names_list = names.splitlines()
    tem = []
    for i in [row for row in names_list if row]:
        tem.append([col for col in list(i) if col != ' '])
    return np.array(tem, dtype=np.int)

In [244]: orig(names)                                                                
Out[244]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
In [245]: timeit orig(names)                                                         
11.1 µs ± 194 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`genfromtxt` does basically the same thing - split lines, collect values in a list of lists, and turn that into an array.  It is not compiled.

The flagged answer replaces the list comprehension with a `split` method:

```
def czisws(names):
    names_list = names.splitlines()
    tem = []
    for i in [row for row in names_list if row]:
        tem.append(i.split())
    return np.array(tem, dtype=np.int)

In [247]: timeit czisws(names)                                                       
8.58 µs ± 274 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It is faster, which isn't surprising.  `split` is a string method.  Builtin methods typically are faster, and preferable even if they aren't.

Split is also more general purpose:

```
In [251]: 'abc de f'.split()                                                         
Out[251]: ['abc', 'de', 'f']
In [252]: [i for i in list('abc de f') if i!=' ']                                    
Out[252]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.genfromtxt`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

names = """
1 2 1
1 1 0
0 1 1
"""
print(np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(names), dtype=np.int)) #Python3 use BytesIO(names.encode('utf-8'))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039690/numpy-throws-error-while-using-genfromtxt-function-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.genfromtxt` as follows for `Python 3`

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

names = """
1 2 1
1 1 0
0 1 1
"""
print(np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(names.encode('utf-8')), dtype=np.int))
#print(np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(names), dtype=np.int)) for Python 2
```

You will get output as

```
[[1 2 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```