# Read, Transform, and Write Column Contents of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to change a column of dates in my .csv file from month/day/year, to timestamp format.

I would like to change this...

```
VIX Close,Date,VIX High,VIX Low,VIX Open  
18.22,1/2/2004,18.68,17.54,17.96  
17.49,1/5/2004,18.49,17.44,18.45  
16.73,1/6/2004,17.67,16.19,17.66  
15.5,1/7/2004,16.75,15.5,16.72
```

to this...

```
VIX Close,Date,VIX High,VIX Low,VIX Open  
18.22,1073023200.0,18.68,17.54,17.96  
17.49,1073282400.0,18.49,17.44,18.45  
16.73,1073368800.0,17.67,16.19,17.66  
15.5,1073455200.0,16.75,15.5,16.72
```

I've tried many things, and I can get it to print out my desired reformatted date but below is one of the many ways I've tried to write it to the csv column.
What's the most pythonic way to get it to read, and immediately write the desired conversion in place without too many steps, which is where things lead for my when I'm trying to make this happen.

```
with open('testvix.csv', 'wb') as myFile:
    reader = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=',')
    reader.writerow([(time.mktime(time.strptime(row[1], "%m/%d/%Y")))])
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm sure I'm missing some kind of iterating through the csv somehow. I haven't been able to source this solution to my problem online yet

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you call the writer `reader`, as if you have no other things to worry about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Comment: "why do you call the writer reader" just from pasting my attempt at the solution from different places online.

Comment: DyZ, my problem is more than 'bytes-like' object problem. I would not have found my solution from the question or answer in the post. My problem was more to do with reading and writing a column in a csv.

Comment: Your problem is that you open the file in the binary mode.

Comment: I appreciate the scruteny. I want Stack Overflow to be the best it can be, but I needed a bit more help on this problem than what was in the post you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")))

# Save to a new file or overwrite your file
df.to_csv('file2.csv', sep=',')
```

> ,VIX Close,Date,VIX High,VIX Low,VIX Open
>   0,18.22,1075586400.0,18.68,17.54,17.96
>   1,17.49,1083358800.0,18.49,17.44,18.45
>   2,16.73,1086037200.0,17.67,16.19,17.66
>   3,15.5,1088629200.0,16.75,15.5,16.72

Comment: Thank you. Though I can do it without importing datetime, without 'date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"' and shortening the longest line to df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y"). Do you want to change your answer and I'll give it the green check?

Comment: What does 'sep=','' and 'lambda x' do?

Comment: @Renoldus I've edited my answer. `sep` determines the csv column separator and lambda is an anonymous function which is applied for each `['Date']` value in each row. It could have been a regular function receives `x` as a date string and returns `time.mktime(time.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")))` just as well.

Comment: Is this 'sep' thing the same thing as the 'delimiter' from the csv module? I think I was close to figuring this out myself with 'delimiter', though I still don't understand why it's needed. I wish I knew. Sorry to nag about it. Why is sep=',' needed when reading and saving?

Comment: CSV files can use different separators (or delimiters). commas, semicolons, pipes, tabs etc. This just specifies how pandas (or the csv module) should read/write the file.

Comment: I've noticed your code put a lone comma in the header at the front, and numbered all of the rows. Is that something you do standard on csv files? Is there an option to stop this from adding on? Also. I noticed if the date is in 12/1/93 (example) format it won't change it unless it's the long line of code you had up before... df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()))

Comment: You can pass `index=False` to `df.to_csv` to remove column indexing. If there are inconsistencies in your date format your should parse each date using `datetime` like before.