# Splitting lines in python 2.7 throws error in Linux, works in Windows

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
d = each_data[0].strip().split("\x0a")
```

works as expected in Windows, but in Linux it throws error below:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

each_data[0] contains two lines

Any clue is appreciated, thank you.

Update:
Please refer to the script here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdivk/solr_demo/master/scripts/script_p2.py

Environment requirement: python 2.6.6 (sorry I Know this is a low version, it is the built-in python we have on all the CentOS with Cloudera CDH installed, it would be un-realistic to upgrade python in a short time and I need this be fixed in shortest time)

Keep in mind: the code is working as expected in Windows in python 2.7

Comment: please provide a minimal runnable example that reproduces your issue and include a full stack trace of the error.

Comment: on windows you are running python 2.7 ... on linux you are running 3.x i think

Comment: Wrong, on Windows it is 2.7, on Linux it is 2.6.6

Comment: each_data[0] is not what you think it is.   Check how it is created.  Also, the "bytes-like object is required" is an error from Python 3.x *it doesn't exist in python 2.x*, so you'll have to revisit your assertion about what python version you're running this on

Comment: Thank you so much for catching it!!! I have both 2 and 3 installed on the host, and was screwed up by the versions, now the script is working!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this one is a near-duplicate of: [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Try writing `split(b"\x0a")` (i.e. with a `b` before the `"\x0a"`). Or, perhaps you have opened the file as a binary file. Try opening it in text mode.

Comment: No, it is not the same case, it works in 3.5 but I need it to run in 2.6.6 which is the built-in python version of our current CDH version. and adding "b" doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have both 2 and 3 installed on the host, and was screwed up by the versions, with the right version be selected to run the script, it is working!

Thank you all for the enlightening.