# Python3 open text file

Tags: python-3.x, utf

I am trying to open a simple text file using

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
F = open(dir_path+"\\sankey2.txt","r")
```

The path to the file is :C:\Users\David\Google Drive\Jobs\1.Efe\Transporte\0.MODEL

Inside the text file is the following text :

```
sankey2.txt
$SETGLOBAL REFERENCIA
```

Now if I run python it gives me the error :

```
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, _io.TextIOWrapper found
```

So I tried the following 2 solutions :
Trying this

```
F = bytes(open(dir_path+"\\sankey2.txt","r"))
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Trying this

```
F = open(dir_path+"\\sankey2.txt","rb")
```

I get

```
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, _io.BufferedReader found
```

It is not entirely clear to me how to solve this problem. Encoding to UTF-8 doesn't help either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Comment: I don't think so, because I try to use regex