# Write to header of csv file with comma delimiter using list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a list of strings in python.

```
header_list = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
```

I want to replace the header row of a cvs file `text.csv` based on `header_list` such that the header will look like this;

```
column_1, column_2, column_3
```

I am using python v3.6

EDIT: Here is the code that I came up with.

```
import csv
with open('text.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(header_list)
```

I get the error;

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t)

Comment: Did my solution work ?

Comment: This question has been answered in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463449/replace-csv-header-without-deleting-the-other-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in byte mode. Instead open it in normal write mode like this:

```
with open('text.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
```

This will let you write stream objects in the csv

Comment: It almost worked. I asked another question to address it. Thank you for your answer. Upvoted but I could not marked it as the correct answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463449/replace-csv-header-without-deleting-the-other-rows