Change fieldnames of a csv.DictReader in Python
I have a CSV file as follows.
oldFile.csv content:
oldHeader1,oldHeader2,oldHeader3
data01,data02,data03
data11,data12,data13
data21,data22,data23

and I want to rename the headers with new ones. Here's the code I use to do this:
import csv

with open("oldFile.csv", "r") as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=",")
    reader.fieldnames = ["newHeader1", "newHeader2", "newHeader3"]
    rows = list(reader)
    with open("newFile.csv", "w", newline="") as output:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)

The problem is that it doesn't change the headers, but adds new ones.
newFile.csv content:
newHeader1,newHeader2,newHeader3
oldHeader1,oldHeader2,oldHeader3
data01,data02,data03
data11,data12,data13
data21,data22,data23

However, the first line of the oldFile.csv is recognized as header, the code:
import csv

with open("oldFile.csv", "r") as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=",")
    print(reader.fieldnames)

shows:
['oldHeader1', 'oldHeader2', 'oldHeader3']

I don't understand why these values are not overwritten but remain when writing.
I could delete the first line e.g. replacing rows = list(reader) with rows = list(reader)[1:], but referring to other stackoverflow questions (e.g. here or here) I have the impression that it should work without and that I'm doing something wrong.
What's the proper way to achieve this?

maybe already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463449/replace-csv-header-without-deleting-the-other-rows

If you have pandas you could do something like this:
df = pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv')
df.rename(columns={'oldHeader1': 'newHeader1'}, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('newFile.csv', index=False)

Or just do following:
import csv


header_map = {
    "oldHeader1": "newHeader1",
    "oldHeader2": "newHeader2",
    "oldHeader3": "newHeader3",
}

with open('test.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infile, \
        open('renamed_test.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:

    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    headers = next(reader)

    headers = [header_map[header] for header in headers if header_map.get(header) is not None]

    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)


Thank you very much for these suggestions, I've just started learning Python and didn't know about the Pandas library.
However, my question relates specifically to the modification of fieldnames of a csv.DictReader object, as mentioned, I have other ways of achieving my goals anyway.
