# Merge multiple json files in one json file

Tags: python, json

I have alot of json files like the following:

e.g.

1.json

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

test.json

```
{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

two.json

```
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}

...
```

I want to merge them all in one json file like:

merge_json.json

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

I have the following code:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        try:
            result.append(json.load(infile))
        except ValueError:
            print(f)

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

But it is not working, I have the following error:

```
merged_file.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Data.py", line 13, in <module>
    json.dump(result, outfile)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 180, in dump
   fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054552

Comment: `cat 1.json test.json two.json > merge_json.json`

Answer (score 2):

The `b` in the mode opens the file in binary mode.

```
with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
```

But `json.dump` writes a string, not bytes. That is because it may contain unicode characters and it's outside the scope of `json` to encode it (e.g. to `utf8`). You can simply open the output file as text by removing the `b`.

```
with open("merged_file.json", "w") as outfile:
```

It will use he default file encoding. You can also specify the encoding with the open command. e.g.:

```
with open("merged_file.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
```

You should also open your file in text mode for the same reasons:

```
with open(f, "r") as infile:
```