# writing data in file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in programming. Just bought a book for beginners in `Python`. In it I got this code:

```
name = input("name")
email = input("whats ure email:) 
favoriteband = input("ure fav band") 
outputString = name + "|" email + "|" + favoriteband 
fileName = name + ".txt"
file = open(fileName, "wb") 
file.write (outputString) 
print (outputString , " saved in ", fileName) 
file.close ()
```

According to book its fine but I got this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I got no clue how to fix it and book isn't explaining this as well.

Comment: Add the closing quotes > `email = input("whats ure email:")`

Comment: Notice the chromacoding in the snippet you've pasted.  It very clearly indicates that you have unbalanced quotes.  That said, examine the argument in `file.write(outputString)`.  Low level file APIs generally want byte arrays.  To use strings, one often needs to wrap the file stream in something higher level, like a print writer.

Comment: sorry i mispelled this line it is: email = input("whats ure email")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some editing (closing quotes and a missing `+`):

```
name = input("name:")
email = input("whats ure email:")
favoriteband = input("ure fav band:")

outputString = name + " | " + email + " | " + favoriteband 
fileName = name + ".txt"
file = open(fileName, "w") #opened in write mode but not in binary
file.write (outputString) 
print (outputString , " saved in ", fileName) 
file.close()
```

You're getting that error because you're writing in binary mode, hence the `b` in `wb` for

`file = open(fileName, "wb")`

Try this instead :

`file = open(fileName, "w")`

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this:

```
name = input("Your name: ")
email = input("Your email: ")
```

The close quotes are needed as has been pointed out.

```
outputString = name + "|" + email + "|" +  favoriteband
```

`outputString` was missing a `+` before `email`

Finally, we need to rewrite you file management:

```
with open(fileName, "a") as file:
  file.write (outputString) 
  print (outputString , " saved in ", fileName)
```

Writing this as a `with` statement guarantees it will close. Using `open(..., "a")` opens the file in "append" mode and lets you write multiple strings to a file of the same name.

Finally, if I can editorialize, I am not a fan of this book so far.

Edit: here is the whole code with fixes, in hopes of getting you there.

```
name = input("name")
email = input("whats ure email:") 
favoriteband = input("ure fav band") 
outputString = name + "|" + email + "|" +  favoriteband 
fileName = name + ".txt"
with open(fileName, "a") as file:
  file.write (outputString) 
  print (outputString , " saved in ", fileName)
```

You can verify it works with:

```
with open(fileName, "r") as file:
  print(file.read())
```

Comment: Going by what the OP wants to understand from that code as he is a beginner, why not just convert his `outputString` to bytes before passing to `file.write()`.

Comment: it is not working. It is Programming for Beginners Mark Lassoff. Hardly any code works.

Comment: @pio I edited in all my code to hopefully help. If it isn't working with my edits then what is the new error?