# Save tuple into csv

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to save my tuple list into csv, but I get an Error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
import csv

data=[('smith, bob',2),('carol',3),('ted',4),('alice',5)]

with open('ur file.csv','wb') as out:

    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow( ['name', 'num']) # here I'm getting the Error
    for row in data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

I expect a csv file with header name and num with the tuple "data"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened the file in binary mode. The csv library works with files using string objects.

```
with open('ur file.csv', 'w') as out:
```

You could also simplify and speed it up using writerows instead of looping over it and doing writerow yourself.

```
import csv

data=[('smith, bob',2),('carol',3),('ted',4),('alice',5)]
data.insert(0, ('Name', 'Number'))

with open('file.csv','w') as out:
    csv.writer(out).writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not see it :D