# PHP openssl_get_privatekey and openssl_sign in Python

Tags: php, python, openssl, cryptography

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of this two line of PHP code in Python?

```
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edited:

```
$fpx_msgToken = "01";
$fpx_msgType = "BE";
$fpx_sellerExId = "ABC000012345";
$fpx_version = "6.0";
/* Generating signing String */
$data = $fpx_msgToken."|".$fpx_msgType."|".$fpx_sellerExId."|".$fpx_version;
/* Reading key */
$priv_key = file_get_contents('C:\\pki-keys\\DevExchange\\EX00002220.key');
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
$fpx_checkSum = strtoupper(bin2hex( $binary_signature ) );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, where **exactly** are you stuck? By googling the first method name, there's a result immediately

Comment: I mean, like @NicoHaase said, by googling 'python cryptography dsa' you can find full examples of how to do that in python.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I need to integrate with a bank payment gateway, they provide us the sample code in PHP, but I use Python. I hv been searching on Google for 2 days and couldn't get the answer, I totally no idea about cryptography and not even know what are the keyword to search. After searching there are too many functions on cryptography, not sure which one does the same jobs. @LLJ97 thanks for the suggested keyword DSA, I found the answer for the second line, looks like is this one "signature = private_key.sign(data, hashes.SHA256()", but the first line still don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution of Python equivalent code for the above PHP code as below.

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
import binascii    

fpx_msg_token = "01"
fpx_msg_type = "BE"
fpx_seller_exchange_id = "ABC0000123"
fpx_version = "6.0"

# Generating signing String
data = "{}|{}|{}|{}".format(fpx_msg_token, fpx_msg_type, fpx_seller_exchange_id, fpx_version)

key_id = open('C:\\pki-keys\\DevExchange\\EX00002220.key').read();

# Check is TraditionalOpenSSL or PKCS8 format 
if key_id.startswith('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY'):
    # TraditionalOpenSSL format;
    priv_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key_id)
else:
    # PKCS8 format;
    priv_key = crypto.load_pkcs12(key_id).get_privatekey()

# return signature is in binary string;
signature_bin_str = crypto.sign(priv_key, data, 'sha1')

# Convert binary string to hexidecimal
signature_hex = binascii.hexlify(signature_bin_str)

# Convert binary to string;
signature = signature_hex.decode("ascii")

# Convert signature to upper case;
fpx_checksum = str(signature).upper()
```

At the end I got the same value as in PHP code.

:)

Answer (score 1):

In python I would use the `cryptography` package.

Examples shown can be found here: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa/

You can create a private key with the following code.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa

private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(key_size=2048, backend=default_backend())
```

This will create the key to generate the signature of your data.

I would suggest you 2048 bits or above for the key length.

The following code is an example for signing a message.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

data = b"this is some test data"
signature = private_key.sign(data, hashes.SHA256())
```

If you now want to verify a signature you have to get the public key from the private key.

```
public_key = private_key.public_key()
public_key.verify(signature, data, hashes.SHA256())
```

This public key corresponds with your private key and is used to verify signatures that were created with your private key.

Don't focus on each line too much, every language and library will have different methods and ways of doing basically the same thing.

Now for a complete example you can just put the above examples together.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa

private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(key_size=2048, backend=default_backend())
data = b"this is some test data"
signature = private_key.sign(data, hashes.SHA256())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
public_key.verify(signature, data, hashes.SHA256())
```

`public_key.verify()` will raise an `InvalidSignature` exception if the signature happens to be invalid (Source: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa/#verification).

Comment: Thanks @LLJ97 ! I have added the full block of the PHP code in the EDITED section of my question above. I still could not understand how to get the $pkeyid from this openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key) in Python. Looks like I need to read the EX00002220.key to get the $pkeyid and use the $pkeyid to perform public_key.verify() to get the signature. Again how do I get the $pkeyid from the key file (EX00002220.key)? Sorry to ask such a silly question, but I really no idea about cryptography.

Comment: `openssl_get_privatekey()` is an alias of `openssl_pkey_get_private()`. It's basically just a function which either reads a file or a key in the PEM format and prepares it for use in the program. So in your code they're reading a file and getting the key. The variable name `$pkeyid` is a pretty bad name since it is misleading. `$pkeyid` IS the private key, just parsed and prepared for use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I got it now. I tested it and got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    data = b"%s|%s|%s|%s" % (fpx_msg_token, fpx_msg_type, fpx_seller_exchange_id, fpx_version)
TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'

Comment: is your data byte like? Be careful of the `b` in front of the example string. You can either do `b"test string"` or `someStringVariable.encode()` to get a bytestring and therefore a byte like object.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment with different error message, previously I forgot to add the "b" in front of my data (b"my.data"), but after I added the b" and got a different error message (see my edited previous comment).

Comment: I think this issue is getting a bit too big for the comments. You can check this question, which had the same error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in

Comment: It's basically just an issue with the type. You need to convert the string to bytes or a byte array

Comment: I just tried my code with python 3.6 and it worked without any problem. If you're using Python 2.x you're out of luck, since there is no byte type in that version. So make sure you're using Python 3.x, of course the best would be python 3.7

Comment: I have tested it again by adding the b in front and has no error now. But I didn't get the same output as PHP. Please refer to the image: http://download.o.my/me/question.jpg 1. The binary signature is difference. 2. The cert/key is not included in my Python code while generating the signature, while it was included in PHP code. 3. The algorithm in PHP is SHA1 while in Python is SHA256 (Is this the same? I am not sure). Thanks again @LLJ97

Comment: 1. The signature is probably different because a different key was used for the signature. 2. The key gets generated in the python code, in the docs of cryptography are examples on how to load a key from a key file. 3. No, you can look up the hashing algorithms in the docs aswell. Just work through the docs and you will eventually get the result you're looking for:)