# parts = func_name.split('.') TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I'm running a code and I'm getting error for this line:

```
parts = func_name.split('.')
```

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

here parts is showing of type list 
and `func_name` is type of `str`

```
parts = func_name.split('.')
```

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Answer (score 3):

You may have to decode the string before calling the split function, depending of how you get it.

The func_name is in your case a byte array, so you can :

- use a binary string to split

  parts = func_name.split(b'.')
- or decode your string according to its encoding, example for utf-8 :

  parts = func_name.decode().split('.')