# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' : TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, sniffing

I'm building a sniffing tool using python-3.7 and i got that error when i was trying to use the `scapy_http` module.

It works fine in python-2.x.
The object type is `scapy.layers.l2.Ether`

```py
def process(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPResponse):
        print(packet)
```

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sniffer.py", line 13, in
> <module>
>     sniff("wlan0")   File "sniffer.py", line 6, in sniff
>     scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False,prn=process)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 886,
> in sniff
>     r = prn(p)   File "sniffer.py", line 10, in process
>     print(packet)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 438, in
> __str__
>     return str(self.build())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 556, in
> build
>     p = self.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in
> do_build
>     pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in
> do_build_payload
>     return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in
> do_build
>     pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in
> do_build_payload
>     return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in
> do_build
>     pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in
> do_build_payload
>     return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in
> do_build
>     pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in
> do_build_payload
>     return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 538, in
> do_build
>     pkt = self.self_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 227,
> in self_build
>     return _self_build(self, field_pos_list)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 101,
> in _self_build
>     val = _get_field_value(obj, f.name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 74,
> in _get_field_value
>     headers = _parse_headers(val)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 18,
> in _parse_headers
>     headers = s.split("\r\n") TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: replace `"\r\n"` with `b"\r\n"`

Comment: @Cologler Did not work at all. I started the program then nothing was detected even thought I was browsing !! Thanks...

Comment: Seems like this is a bug with scapy_http, you should create an issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in ?

Comment: add a `print(s, type(s))` before the line throwing the error and show what is prints

Comment: Try to change tag from scrapy to scapy, maybe you will get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scapy_http` is deprecated (doesn't work with Python 3), and the HTTP module is now included by default in Scapy.

Please upgrade to the GitHub version or the latest RC:

```
pip install scapy --upgrade --pre
```