# Binary text isn't found in a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, binaryfiles

I opened a file in binary mode. I need to find a certain string inside this file and print the line after that. However, the string doesn't appear to be found in the text file. I looked into the text file manually, and the string is definitely found on one line.

I tried opening the file as textfile (not binary mode) and not making the string binary, but that gave an error that I solved with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in). The answer on that question led to the below (and current) code.

```py
with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'rb') as read_obj:
    # print(read_obj.read())
    for line in read_obj:
        line_number += 1
        if b"PREPARED FOR" in line:
            break
        print(line_number)
```

Comment: Maybe its in unicode?

Comment: Also maybe the string is split over multiple lines and not all in a single one

Comment: Does it appear if you browse the file in text mode?

Comment: @KaseyChang Yes, it does appear when looking at the file manually.

Comment: @LukaKostic no, I can find the text all on one line when browsing the file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So. Apparently `.readlines()` worked. I just had to read all the lines, loop through them. Find the one that had the string in it, call that index and add one to find the next line.