# Merging 2 binary files and read them

Tags: python

I have two files that I want to merge in the same file, and afterwards read them. One is an image with almost all values equals, and hence is only 400 bytes size, and the second one is a map of probabilities that is between 50 and 100kb.

My idea is to open them in binary mode and append them. However, later I want to be able to read them. How can I read this structure? Should I merge the files like: size of small+small+large?

To write them I was thinking on doing:

```
# Small = input1, large = input2
input1 = open('input1.bin', 'rb').read()
input2 = open('input2.bin', 'rb').read()

input1 += input2 

with open('Output.bin', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(input1)
```

Comment: Have a look at : [Merge Two Binary Files Into Third Binary File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050356/merge-two-binary-files-into-third-binary-file)

Comment: I would rather use `pickle` module

Comment: These are completely different file types: an image and a probability map. Why do you want to merge it into a single file? That is very confusing.

Comment: If you want to do it by yourself, you must create some structure to the file: Allocate 4 bytes for the size of the first file followed by another 4 bytes for the size of the second file, or include an offset to the beginning of each file, or whatever hint that will help you to know where each file begins and ends.

Comment: I want to do this because I generate over 150.000 files of 400 bytes and 150.000 files of 100kb. I need to store them, then I open 1000 in an iteration (1000 for 400bytes and 1000 for 100kb). I need to do this in parallel in a webserver, where there can be thousands of request in parallel. I think that by opening just a single file per interation instead of two I save IOPS. This is just one strategy I want to try. Anything else in a coding format?

Comment: That context is much more important! You're free to ask how to store two binary files in a single file, but given there are already several suggestions in the comments, the context is very important. Your actual problem may perhaps be better answered on another part of the stackexchange site; I don't know about that.

Comment: Are you technically still serving a single file over the webserver to the client? Or just the data/bytes? In the latter case, would having more files in a single file, and then in memory, be potentially even faster?

Comment: Note that I think that having 150,000 files on a file system (that assumes 2 data types in a single file, as per the question), is still far too many to be efficient. Perhaps you generate them on the fly and keep them in memory instead, but your comment suggest you end up with 150,000 (or 300,000) files on disk. That's likely a problem already, with or without combining files.

Comment: What's the problem on having 3·10^5 files in a disk? I generate them during a long run process, and later when the user asks I need to read 1000 (400b) and 1000 (100kb) in an iteration where for each iteration i read 1 of 400b and 1 of 100kb. I do not return these files to an user. In each iteration I do a calculus with these files. There's no writing of files.

Comment: Perhaps there is no problem. But have you tried it (i.e., without the web serving part)? Create 300,000 files of a few kb each, then select 1,000 of them. Or try to list them.

Comment: What system (OS, hardware) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful "struct" library for someone. Here is my solution:

```
# Saving file jointly
input1 = open('file1', 'rb').read()
input2 = open('file2', 'rb').read()
filesize = len(input1).to_bytes(4, 'big')
output = filesize + input1 + input2

with open('Output.bin', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(output)

# Open them
input1 = open('Output.bin', 'rb').read()
filesize2 = int.from_bytes(input1[:4], "big")

file1 = input1[4:4+filesize2]
file2 = input1[4+filesize2:]
```

**UPDATE**:

Although this approach works well, if you don't mind to waste a few kb per combined file you can also try pickle. Joining a 400 bytes image to a 57kb npz file I have noticed that the combined file is 57kb with the previous routine, but 78kb with pickle. However, pickle beats in speed as it reduces by half the speed of binary.

Finally, in my case my npz file had a structure that I later had to read,

```
npz = npz['mystructure']
```

This step is very slow, and by preparing it with pickle previously, the difference is orders of magnitude...

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import time
from io import BytesIO
import pickle

filename = "MYFILENAME"

# Saving file jointly BYTES
image = open(f'{filename}.png', 'rb').read()
npz = open(f'{filename}.npz', 'rb').read()
filesize = len(image).to_bytes(4, 'big')
output = filesize + image + npz

with open('Output.bin', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(output)

# Saving file jointly PICKLE
image = open(f'{filename}.png', 'rb').read()
image = Image.open(f"{filename}.png") 
npz = np.load(f'{filename}.npz')
npz = npz['mystructure']

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump([image, npz], handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# READING TEST
now = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    # Open them
    input1 = open('Output.bin', 'rb').read()
    filesize2 = int.from_bytes(input1[:4], "big")
    
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(input1[4:4+filesize2])) 
    npz = np.load(BytesIO(input1[4+filesize2:]))
    #npz = npz['mystructure']

print(f"BINARY lasts {time.time()-now} seconds")

now = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    # Open them
    with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        b = pickle.load(handle)
        image = b[0]
        npz = b[1]

print(f"PICKLE lasts {time.time()-now} seconds")

now = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    npz = np.load(f"{filename}.npz", mmap_mode='r')
    image = Image.open(f"{filename}.png") 
    #npz = npz['mystructure']

print(f"2 FILES lasts {time.time()-now} seconds")
```