# My script works well in Python 2 but not in python 3- TypeError

Tags: python

This is just a part of my script :

This script is to extract data from a logfile to a text file.

```
self.cut.start_line='test started'

def extract_data(self):
    data=None
    for line in self.file_content:
        if data is None: 
            if self.start_line in line:   #search for 'test started'
                data=[]     
        elif self.end_line in line:    
            break   
        else:       
            data.append(line)
    return data
```

I wrote this script using `Python 2` but when I run in `Python 3` it shows:

```
>>> if self.start_line in line:   #search for 'test started'
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Make start_line a byte string: `b'test started'`

Comment: `self.file_content` is bytes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in

Answer (score 1):

This is arising because while reading the logfile, you must have openedn the file in `"rb"` mode. This means in binary mode.

Now while doing comparison also it is asking to provide a binary substring for checking.

Now, you can solve this in 2 ways :

1. Either convert your search string into binary.

```
self.cut.start_line=b'test started'
```

2. Open the logfile for reading in simple mode, i.e., not binary mode [use "`r"` instead of `"rb"`].

Comment: my reading mode is in 'r' mode btw. okay i will try to do the first way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`line` must be a `str` or `start_line` must be a bytes object

Two options:

**Use `b'test started'`**

```py
self.cut.start_line=b'test started'

def extract_data(self):
    data=None
    for line in self.file_content:
        if data is None: 
            if self.start_line in line:   #search for 'test started'
                data=[]     
        elif self.end_line in line:    
            break   
        else:       
            data.append(line)
    return data
```

**Use `line.decode()`**

```py
self.cut.start_line='test started'

def extract_data(self):
    data=None
    for line in self.file_content:
        line = line.decode()
        if data is None: 
            if self.start_line in line:   #search for 'test started'
                data=[]     
        elif self.end_line in line:    
            break   
        else:       
            data.append(line)
    return data
```

Comment: Thank you! i tried to do the first option. works well for my script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `encode()` function to encode the string to bytes.

```
self.cut.start_line='test started'.encode()
```

If you want to get back the original string, use the `decode()` function. If `self.cut.start_line` is the encoded text, then

```
self.cut.start_line.decode()
```

will give back the original string.