# Plotly Dash: How to reproduce 'content' Output of dcc.Upload? (i.e. base64 encoded string)

Tags: python, excel, io, base64, plotly-dash

I am not able to reproduce the exact output of the `content`-property of the dcc.Upload component.

If I upload the file `my_excel.xlsx` to the dcc.Upload component, my callback-function receives a "base64 encoded string" (according to the [dcc.Upload documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload)). I don’t know how to reproduce the exact same string **without** the dcc.Upload component (I want to use the Output for Unit Tests).

my current approach:

```
import base64
import io
import pandas as pd

# This is what I try to reproduce the output of the dcc.Upload Component
with open('tests/data/my_excel.xlsx', 'rb') as file:
    raw_data = file.read()
    
# raw_data is the output I receive from the dcc.Upload Component

# these steps are raise no Error with the output of dcc.Upload
_, content_string = raw_data.split(',') # this Fails
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
```

I get the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

if I add

```
raw_data = base64.b64encode(raw_data)
```

before the `raw_data.split(',')`, I get the same error.

How do I get the exact same "base64 encoded string" without the dcc.Upload Component?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find a single function to reproduce the `contents` property of dcc.Upload, but was able to manually create the output of dcc.Upload.

From the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) we have:

> `contents` is a base64 encoded string that contains the files contents
> [...]  Property `accept` (string; optional): Allow specific types of
> files. See https://github.com/okonet/attr-accept for more information.
> Keep in mind that mime type determination is not reliable across
> platforms. CSV files, for example, are reported as text/plain under
> macOS but as application/vnd.ms-excel under Windows. In some cases
> there might not be a mime type set at all.

Inspecting the `contents`-string reaveals, that it is composed of two strings:

```py
content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
```

Inspecting further shows:
`content_type`: contains mime type information of file
`content_string`: the base64 encoded content of the file

```py
import base64
import io
import pandas as pd
import magic

filepath = 'tests/data/my_excel.xlsx'

# Reproduce output of dcc.Upload Component
with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
    decoded = file.read()
content_bytes = base64.b64encode(decoded)
content_string = content_bytes.decode("utf-8")

mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime_type = mime.from_file(filepath)
content_type = "".join(["data:", mime_type, ";base64"])

contents = "".join([content_type, ",", content_string])

# and now revert: convert contents to binary file stream
content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
```