# Reading .csv in AWS S3 for DynamoDB with Lambda - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a lambda function that adds data from a .csv file in AWS S3 to DynamoDB using the following Python code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")

def lambda_function(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    
    rows = obj['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
    
    table = dynamodb.Table('Sports_Scores')
    
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item={
                
                "sport_type":row.split(b",")[0],
                "team_name":row.split(b",")[1],
                "game_date":row.split(b",")[2],
                "opposing_team":row.split(b",")[3],
                "team_score":int(row.split(",")[4]),
                "opposing_score":int(row.split(",")[5]),
                "won_lost":row.split(b",")[6]
            })
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_function    "team_score":int(row.split(",")[4]),
```

I tried changing it to byte: `"team_score":int(row.split(b",")[4]),` but I get another error:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'team_score'Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_function"team_score":int(row.split(b",")[4]),
```

I am very new to Lambda and DynamoDB, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your CSV file has a header.  You're trying to add the header row, so it fails trying to convert the string 'team_score" to an integer.  The easy way to get around that is to skip it: add `if row.startswith('sport'): continue` after `for row in rows`.

Comment: @TimRoberts made the change and ran into another error: `An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Requested resource not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_function
    batch.put_item(Item={`

Comment: Look at this may be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in