# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str', for writing string to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte

```
            for d in range(0,d2.size):
                c2 += str(d2.item(d))
            cf.write(chr(int(c2,2)))
```

Getting error in cf.write(chr(int(c1,2)))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Code was running fine on python 2.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Comment: Can you post with what arguments the file (cf) was opened? I think the issue is you're opening the file with the 'rb' argument.

Comment: @kinshukdua 
`cf = open(f+".ctxt","wb")`

Comment: I've posted an answer that should solve your problem. Upvote and select it as the answer if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you said that you were opening the file as a bytes by using the argument `wb` however you're trying to write a `string` to the file which causes the error.

To fix that all you have to do is convert the string to bytes

```
for d in range(0,d2.size):
    c2 += str(d2.item(d))
    cf.write(bytes(chr(int(c2,2)), 'utf-8'))
```