# how to read multiple dictionaries from a file in python which contains bytes-like object?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I'm trying to read a txt file containing multiple dictionaries. The file has the following format:

```
/* 1 */
{
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2
}

/* 2 */
{
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2
}

/* 3 */
{
}...
```

I'm trying to read it as a list of dictionaries. Is there any way to remove that /* x */ thing and do the needful?
I tried the following piece of code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import ast
  
with open('doc.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
d = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove  ***/* x */***  You can use **regular expression**

```
import ast
import re
  
with open('doc.txt') as f:
    data = re.sub("/\*.*\*/", "", f.read())

d = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

you can find more in official documentation: [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: It won't be able to read as the file contains byte-like objects '/* x */'

Comment: hope this helps you [a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)   @SrGrace