# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment to be solved

Tags: python

this is my code
this question submission is also giving me errors

```
import numpy as np

row=6
col=7
gamelist=[" "*col]*row
def gamefield():
  print("1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
  for i in range(row):
        for j in range (col):
            if j!=6:
              print(gamelist[i][j],end="| ")
              continue
            else:
                print(" ")
        print("---------------------")

gamefield()

def move(r):
  i=0
  while(gamelist[i+1][r]==" "):
    gamelist[i+1][r],gamelist[i][r]=gamelist[i][r],gamelist[i+1][r]
    i=+1
  return i
  
  
poi=1
poi=1
def main ():
  poi=1
  if poi==1:
    r=int(input("Player 1 turn Enter column:"))-1
    if gamelist[0][r]==" ":
      hash="#"
      gamelist[0][r]=gamelist[0][r].replace(" ",hash)
      gamefield()
      row=move(r)
      check(row,r)
    else:
      print("Place occupied")
      poi=2
  else:
    r=int(input("Player 2 turn Enter column:"))-1
    if gamelist[0][r]==" ":
       at="@"
       gamelist[0][r]=at
       gamefield()
       row=move(r)
       check(row,r)
    else:
      print("Place occupied")
      poi=1



def check(r,c):
  while r+3<6:
    while c+3<7:
      if gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+1][c] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+2][c] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+3][c] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c+1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c+2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c+3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c-1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c-2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r][c-3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+1][c+1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+2][c+2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+3][c+3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-1][c-1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-2][c-2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-3][c-3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-1][c+1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-2][c+2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r-3][c+3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      elif gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+1][c-1] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+2][c-2] and gamelist[r][c]==gamelist[r+3][c-3] :
        print("Player",poi,"Wins!!!")
        break
      else:
        print("player",poi," turn over")
        break
    break

print("Connect 4")
if True :
  main()
```

**this is a connect 4 game in python and i have tried it many times to execute but i am getting the same error please help me to resolve it**
i need to complete it asap
please resendto me where i have gone wrong
also how to edit strings in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-to-a-file-in)

Comment: Is that a **minimal** [mre]??  Please always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: You have the answer to your own question at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`gamelist` is a list of strings:

```
>>> row=6
>>> col=7
>>> gamelist=[" "*col]*row
>>> print(gamelist)  
['       ', '       ', '       ', '       ', '       ', '       ']
```

You try to assign a value to one of the characters in a string - You cannot to that.

```
>>> gamelist[0][2] = '5'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

> However, you can use parts of the old string to make a new one.

As pointed out, you solved your problem but didn't implement it. Here is one way to do it.

```
>>> r=2
>>> gamelist[0] = gamelist[0][:r] + 'a' + gamelist[0][r+1:]
>>> gamelist
['  a    ', '       ', '       ', '       ', '       ', '       ']
>>>
```

Comment: Answer specific to OP's situation - marked as wiki to avoid aspersions after closing question as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The `gamelist` matrix itself is not created properly. You need to create the matrix in the following way in order to modify its values-

```
gamelist=[[" "]*col for _ in range(row)]
```