# How to combine images into a PDF ordered by the time that they were taken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, img2pdf

I am attempting to compile a folder of images into a single PDF by the order in which they were taken.

```
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(folder_path)

a= glob.glob(folder_path)
b = [os.path.getctime(i) for i in a]
c = {}
for i,j  in list(zip(a,b)):
    c[i] = j
sorted_c = dict(sorted(c.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=False))
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([k for k in sorted_c]))
```

For some reason

```
 with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([k for k in sorted_c]))
```

keeps throwing  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' Alternate methods to accomplish this are also welcome.

Comment: Help would come quicker if you actually added the error message to your post, which would at least indicate the line of the error.  Which statement gives you the error?

Comment: A wild guess: the error is in `f.write(img2pdf.convert([k for k in sorted_c]))` because `img2pdf.convert()` accepts only files/pdf-like/bytes-like objects as parameters. Is `[k for k in sorted_c]` a `str`/string? Where do you get the error? Please [edit] the question to include necessary details.

Comment: You are correct, the error is in f.write(img2pdf.convert([k for k in sorted_c])) , [k for k in sorted_c] is a list

Comment: @The Amateur Coder: The [docs](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) state that it accepts a list of filenames.

Comment: @azelcer, oh, but then where could the error occur? Silly me, it's because the file is opened in `"wb"` mode; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054552/16136190).

Comment: Can you check your python an img2pdf versions?

Comment: Why would that be necessary? Did they change anything/the `convert()` method, or are the versions different?

Comment: The mode change does not work, it has been tried :/