# How to prevent Python JSON .dumps() function from removing carriage return?

Tags: python, json, line-endings

In Python, I'm attempting to read in a JSON file, change a single value, then do some further processing on the string returned from the `.dumps()` function. However, after calling `json.dumps()` the string that is returned has removed the `/r` characters.

It is important for my application the original formatting is maintained. The [documentation for json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) does not have a way to specify line endings. I can't see what else could be causing this removal.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to maintain line endings without having to strong-arm the output (i.e. replace, writing to a new file with correct line endings, etc.)?

As a simple example:

```py
with open('./test.json', 'rb') as test_file:
   for line in test_file:
      print(line)
      # This prints lines that look like:
      # b'{\r\n'
      # b'   "yay": "JSON!"\r\n'
      # b'}'
   test_file.seek(0,0)
   
   json_object = json.load(test_file)
   json_dump = json.dumps(json_object, indent=3)
   print(repr(json_dump))
   # This prints:
   # '{\n   "yay": "JSON!"\n}'
   #    ^\r removed       ^\r removed
```

**EDIT**

To clarify against [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842875/how-to-explicitly-set-carriage-return-when-doing-json-dump). I am hoping I can do this without modifying the existing file or writing to a new one. In other words, I want the string returned from `.dumps()` to maintain the same line-endings as the file. However, thanks to helpful comments below. I see this really is not the intention of the JSON package. The JSON package only conveys *JSON* data, making no promises about formatting. Sounds like to get what I want I'll need to either write to a new file or do some string formatting myself. Thanks all!

Comment: Why do you need the carriage returns preserved? I'm not even sure that's part of the JSON spec

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format. The `\r ` is not part of your data. If you need the carriage return in a file, you are usually better indicating that when you save (for example passing the `newline` argument to [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)).

Comment: You cannot *preserve* the carriage returns, because they were already necessarily lost during the parsing, because they **do not carry semantic information** in the JSON format. However, you can *choose* whether to output carriage returns along with newline characters when you output the file (along with also having the option to put it all on one lines) - by configuring *the file object*, not the `json.dumps` call. Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Summarized my thoughts in an edit above, but sounds like this package is not really meant to be used this way, nor does the JSON spec make any promises about formatting (makes sense). It's clear where my issue now lies. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

> without having to strong-arm the output (i.e. replace, writing to a new file with correct line endings, etc.)?

It's not much work: you can specify the newlines you wish to use when you [open the output file](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open("test.json", "w", newline="\r\n") as f:
    f.write('{\n   "yay": "JSON!"\n}')
```

> When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.linesep). If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

This should also work if you're writing back to the source file:

```
with open("test.json", "r+", newline="\r\n") as f:
    my_dict = json.loads(f.read())

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets. I'm now realizing my question sounded similar to [the question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842875/how-to-explicitly-set-carriage-return-when-doing-json-dump). In my case, I was hoping to not need to use another file, but sounds like I'll need to use another file to use your suggestion, which seems like the path of least resistance at this point. Thanks!

Comment: @cam.b, if you're not writing back to a file why does it matter whether there's a carriage return or not? It certainly sounded like you wanted to write this data back. I understood that you had another process reading this data afterwards.

Comment: doing a hash on byte-level information of the file, after doing some processing of the file via the JSON component, is what I'm after. Should have made that clearer, my apologies!